# getting java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String when using proper format %f for doubles

Tags: java, number-formatting

The following code from the main is suppose to output the result to two decimal places using System.out.printf to format a double value with %f.
However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
The total bonus for this employee is $  at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at Assignment1.Q2.TestBonusOnSavings.main(TestBonusOnSavings.java:36)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

**Part of the code with the formatted print statement:**

```
  //Displays the total bonus for an employee
  BonusOnSavings bonus = new BonusOnSavings();
  System.out.printf("The total bonus for this employee is $%,.2f",
                    bonus.computeBonus(commitment, q1, q2, q3, q4) + "\n");
```

Comment: What do you think `+ "\n"` does?

Comment: That's not your actual code. `System.out.println` only takes 1 parameter; this would not compile as-is. Please show your actual code that you run to get this exception, along with the inputs and the definition of `bonus.computeBonus`.

Comment: Use `String.format`

Comment: Based on the stack trace (`printFloat` followed by `failConversion`), I'm thinking that one of your parameters is not a `float` and should be.

Comment: All parameters "commitment, q1, q2, q3, and q4" are all double.

Comment: computeBonus may or may not be returning a double, but you're append a newline character to it.   Take that out and put it in the format string.